# About the topology of the Heisenberg group

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, connectedness

By definition, if $A$ is simply-connected then $A$ is connected.

I would like to know why in the Wikipedia we find this phrase: 
"The Heisenberg group is a **connected**, **simply-connected** Lie group ...", because it is sufficient to say "The Heisenberg group is a **simply-connected** Lie group ..." only.

My problem is, why connected **and** simply-connected (both at the same time), it is sufficient to write just simply-connected.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe also because the way to prove each one are not of the same nature (purely topological for the first case).

Answer (score 0):

Simply connected means that any closed curve is homotopic to the constant curve. If you take two copies of a simply connected space - for example two disjoint points - they are still simply connected, but not connected.